# Example of a Dedekind Finite Ring Which is Not Stably Finite

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that there is a Dedekind Finite Ring which is not Stably Finite. Shephardson has given such an example. I need some different example. Can anyone supply me another example?

Comment: How about you give Shephardson's example? It is not very considerate to force all the readers to try to hunt down the example you have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shephardson's construction is in the $2\times 2$-case. P.M. Cohn has generalized this and has constructed for any $n\ge 2$ a ring $R$, which is Dedeking finite for all $r\le n$, but $M_{n+1}(R)$ is *not* Dedekind finite, i.e., $R$ is not stably finite. See his paper "Some remarks on invariant basis property", Topology $5$, $1966$, $215-228$. For more information see also Lam's book "Exercises in Modules and Rings".